# Cannot get response from mailchimp API

Tags: python, api, python-requests, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3

I need to connect mailchimp API through python script and GET data, that i'd later move to PowerBI for BI solutions.

I have read the documentation :
https://mailchimp.com/developer/guides/get-started-with-mailchimp-api-3/#Parameters

And I am trying to get a specific report
https://mailchimp.com/developer/reference/reports/#get_/reports/-campaign_id-

First I managed to connect to reports (https://mailchimp.com/developer/reference/reports/#get_/reports/) with the following code:

```
import requests
import json

r=requests.get("https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/reports/", 
               headers={"content-type": "application/json"}, 
               auth=('anystring', 'myapikey')
               ,params={'fields':['id']})

data=r.json()
print(data)
r_dict = json.loads(r.text)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)

for i in r_dict:
   print("key:", i,"val",r_dict[i])
```

Then I get some sort of output, which is not an error and it seems i connected since i retrieved data. Now I am trying to connect to a specific report, i set up an id, but it seems i cannot understand how to set up parameters properly. My code looks like this:

```
r=requests.get("https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/reports/{80419197aa}", 
               headers={"content-type": "application/json"}, 
               auth=('anystring', 'myapikey')
               ,params={'fields':['id','campaign_title','type','list_id']})

data=r.json()
print(data)
r_dict = json.loads(r.text)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)

for i in r_dict:
    print("key:", i,"val",r_dict[i])
```

Then i get this error:

> {'type':
>   'http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/',
>   'title': 'Resource Not Found', 'status': 404, 'detail': 'The requested
>   resource could not be found.', 'instance':
>   '13af7a5e-9868-4dd3-abd6-6c3b0b58983f'} 404
>   {"type":"http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/","title":"Resource
>   Not Found","status":404,"detail":"The requested resource could not be
>   found.","instance":"13af7a5e-9868-4dd3-abd6-6c3b0b58983f"} key: type
>   val
>   http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/
>   key: title val Resource Not Found key: status val 404 key: detail val
>   The requested resource could not be found. key: instance val
>   13af7a5e-9868-4dd3-abd6-6c3b0b58983f"

Could anyone help me how should i specify the parameters, because i suppose the mistake is there?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why error 404 appears is because of the `auth` parameter, if you remove this parameter you will get the error 401 that is an invalid API Key, you would need to use the correct authentication method.

I would recommend that you first try it with a program like **Postman**, so that you discard some error outside the code.